# How to use "case when" from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

My database tables, i need to get the "NEW_IC_NO" from these two tables if they found matched.

### TB_A

[image]

### TB_B

[image]

Comment: It's very unclear what you're looking for here. Why are you focussing on `CASE WHEN`? What results do you want?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `CASE WHEN`, use a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT a.NEW_IC_NO
FROM TB_A a
INNER JOIN TB_B b ON a.NEW_IC_NO = b.NEW_IC_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join or any join..

Example

Select * from TB_A as A inner join TB_B as B on A.NEW_IC_NO = B.NEW_IC_NO.